# Problem with gcc -c parameter and set an outfile

Tags: c, gcc

I've a question about GCC and objects file..

In few words when I try to do this command:

```
gcc -Wall -o obj/config.o -c global.h config/config.c
```

It's simply returns this **fatal error**:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

I've tried to search on Google, but I've not found anything about it.
Maybe I used wrong keywords...
Anyone can help?

Comment: things gone wrong also if I use only "-o config.o"

Comment: why are you specifiying the `global.h` (isn't it included?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.h` header files don't get directly compiled, only `.c` source files. Get rid of `global.h`.

```
gcc -Wall -o obj/config.o -c config/config.c
```

Comment: gcc allows direct compilation of `h` files with the default behaviour based on file extension being to generate a precompiled header. (Probably not what OP wants though)